# Handling Stripes payment_intent.succeeded Webhook if it competes with a post back from the client to create an entity in the DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, stripe-payments

I need some advice on the workflow for my application when charging a credit card using Stripe.

**Scenario 1** - I don't use any webhook for `payment_intent.succeeded` so when I call stripe.confirmCardPayment on the client side in Javascript
and receive the paymentIntent back I then post to my server and create an entry in a "Payment" table with some method called "SavePayment()", where all the details (card id, exp month, amount, etc) will be stored. Once I save to the DB, I can return the details to the client (points earned, payment successful message, etc). Then we're done!

**Scenario 2** Client(user) closes the browser after Stripe is called to charge the card, but before it can post back to my server to add the "Payment" entity. So now I use a webhook for `payment_intent.succeeded` as others have recommended doing this for redundancy.

**Problem** -

Because the webhook is triggered immediately, after the card is charged by Stripe, my server could potentially receive two different entry points (client posting back to server to save a payment and Stripes webhook trigger event), to create a "Payment" entity in my DB.

Now this isn't a huge problem, because both entry points can query for the "Payment" entity based on it's unique identifier (PaymentIntentId) to see if it exists in the DB.

But let's say both entry points query and return a null, so now both entry points go ahead and create a new "Payment" entity and attempt to save it in the DB. One will succeed and one will now fail, frequently creating a unique identifier constraint exception being thrown by SQL Server.

**Solution?** - This doesn't seem like the ideal workflow/scenario, where multiple exceptions could be frequently thrown, for creating an entity in my DB. Is there a better workflow for this, or am I stuck implementing it this way?

Here is some of my code/suedo code to look at.

```
public class Payment : BaseEntity
{
    public string PaymentIntentId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string CardBrand { get; set; }
    public string CardExpMonth { get; set; }
    public string CardExpYear { get; set; }
    public int CardFingerPrint { get; set; }
    public string CardLastFour { get; set; }
    public PaymentStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int StripeFee { get; set; }
    public int PointsAwarded { get; set; }
    public int PointsBefore { get; set; }
    public int PointsAfter { get; set; }
    public string StripeCustomer { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Here is some code from the client to call stripe and then post to my server

```js
// submit button is pressed 
// do some work here then call Stripe

from(this.stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.paymentIntent.clientSecret, data)).subscribe((result: any) => {

  if (result.paymentIntent) {

    let payment = {
      paymentIntentId: result.paymentIntent.id,
      amount: result.paymentIntent.amount,
      currency: result.paymentIntent.currency,
      // fill in other fields
    };

    this.accountService.savePayment(payment).subscribe(response => {

      if (response.status === 'Success') {
        // do some stuff here
        this.alertService.success("You're purchase was successful");
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/somepage');
      }

      if (response.status === 'Failed') {
        this.alertService.danger("Failed to process card");
      }

    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.alertService.danger("Oh no! Something happened, please contact the help desk.");
    }).add(() => {
      this.loadingPayment = false;
    });

  } else {
    this.loadingPayment = false;
    this.alertService.danger(result.error.message);
  }

});
```

Here is the server controller to save a "Payment" entity

```
        [HttpPost("savepayment")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SavePayment(StripePaymentDto paymentDto)
    {
        var userFromRepo = await _userManager.FindByEmailFromClaimsPrinciple(HttpContext.User);
        
        if (userFromRepo == null) 
            return Unauthorized(new ApiResponse(401));
        // this calls the Stripe API to get the PaymentIntent (just incase the client changed it)
        var paymentIntent = await _paymentService.RetrievePaymentIntent(paymentDto.PaymentIntentId);
        if (paymentIntent == null) return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Problem Retrieving Payment Intent"));

        var payment = _mapper.Map<StripePaymentDto, StripePayment>(paymentDto);
        payment.UserId = userFromRepo.Id;

        if (paymentIntent.Status == "succeeded") {
           
            // fill in all the necessary fields
            // left out for brevity

        } else if (paymentIntent.Status == "requires_payment_method") {
            payment.Status = PaymentStatus.Failed;
            _logger.LogInformation("Payment Intent is not successful. Status: " + paymentIntent.Status + " PaymentIntentId: " + paymentIntent.PaymentIntentId);
            // send payment failure email
        } else {
            // don't know if this will be needed
            payment.Status = PaymentStatus.Pending;
        }

        _unitOfWork.Repository<StripePayment>().Add(payment);

        var success = await _unitOfWork.Complete();
        if (success > 0) {
            if (payment.Status == PaymentStatus.Success) {
                // send email
            }
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<StripePayment, StripePaymentDto>(payment));
        }
        
        return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Failed to save payment"));

    }
```

Here is the Stripe webhook

```
    [HttpPost("webhook")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> StripeWebhook()
    {
        var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        // if this doesn't match we get an exception (sig with whSec) 
        var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json, Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], _whSecret);

        PaymentIntent intent; 

        switch (stripeEvent.Type)
        {
            case "payment_intent.succeeded":
                intent = (PaymentIntent)stripeEvent.Data.Object;
                _logger.LogInformation("Payment Succeeded: ", intent.Id);
                this.ProcessSuccess(intent);
                // order  = await _paymentService.UpdateOrderPaymentSucceeded(intent.Id);
                // _logger.LogInformation("Order updated to payment received: ", order.Id);
                break;
            case "payment_intent.payment_failed":
                intent = (PaymentIntent)stripeEvent.Data.Object;
                _logger.LogInformation("Payment Failed: ", intent.Id);
                // _logger.LogInformation("Payment Failed: ", order.Id);
                break;
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    private async void ProcessSuccess(PaymentIntent paymentIntent) {
        
        var spec = new PaymentsWithTypeSpecification(paymentIntent.Id);
        var paymentFromRepo = await _unitOfWork.Repository<StripePayment>().GetEntityWithSpec(spec);

        if (paymentFromRepo == null) {
            // create one and add it
            var payment = _mapper.Map<PaymentIntent, StripePayment>(paymentIntent);
            payment.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(paymentIntent.Metadata["userid"]);
        }

        // finish work here and then save to DB

    }
```

Comment: me again! as I answered on the other thread, you should consider building a queueing system to you serially process any reads/writes to your database, both for your incoming webhook event and also your client-side requests to your server.

Comment: I don't think creating a queue is a good solution.

Comment: Why not just handle the exception in the webhook listener - if you get the error, and the record now exists in the database, continue as normal? For transient errors, stripes webhooks have some retry logic built in so should be fairly robust anyway - https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic

Comment: Hi Sam. I think that might be what I have to do, but I'll have to deal with the exception on both the controller end and the webhook end, as both will be coming in to contend for the creation of the DB row entry. It just doesn't seem like sound logic to catch an exception for every row entry of this type?? Which is what would happen as each entry points will create try to create the DB row.

Answer (score -1):

Great point below. I appreciate your goal. After some thought, my final analysis is that: in order to prevent duplicate records in the database from multiple sources, a unique index should be used. (which you are using)

Now by using a unique index the database will throw an exception which the code will have to handle gracefully. Hence the answer is that you are doing it the way I and others have done so for some years. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other means of avoiding an exception once you hit the database tier.

Great question even if the answer is not the one you were hoping for.

Comment: Hi Jon. I just read through the link you provided, but I'm a little confused and have a question or 2. I don't need to update this row, only add it once when the purchase is made. In my scenario UserA(client posting to the controller) and UserB(webhook) will be in contention for creating and adding it to the table, so will this RowVersion implementation work for my scenario? It doesn't seem like it would! Or does RowVersion usually apply to updating the same row with different values?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's my understanding that rowversion is meant to prevent updating the same row with different values so it should prevent contention from 2 different sources because it is maintained in the database.

Comment: Hi Jon. Maybe I misunderstand you, but you say "It's my understanding that rowversion is meant to prevent updating the same row with different values" but I'm never updating this row after it gets created. It gets created once and that's it. The contention comes from the creation of the row, not some update. So, unless I read the documentation incorrectly that you left a link for, I don't think I can use it??